# How to generate FOS UserBundle views

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOS User bundle to allow users to register and log in to my app. Until now it works just fine but i don't know how to get my hand on those views? Can i generate them somehow? [Documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) doesnt seem to know anything about it, just about overriding templates, which is not what i need...

At first i thought routing file might be of some use, since it points to specific places in the project, but it lists folders I dont even have in my application

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

There is no FOSUserBundle directory at all...

Comment: great, post it as answer and i will mark it as accepted if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find third party bundles installed in the `vendor` directory.

In this case, `@FOSUserBundle` should be a pointer to `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/`.

If you don't have that directory, try running this on your project root: `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding templates is well documented [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html)